# Updating an ACF user field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a pretty simple events plugin and on the event page am wanting to allow the user to mark themselves as attending. The site is a members-style site where everyone has to be logged in to access it.

I have a ACF user field set up and just a simple form with one button. the idea is that the user clicks the button and their user gets added to that ACF field. Iv already got checks in place to see if their user is already in that field, and if so to not show the button.

Anyway, below is what i have but for some reason or another it doesnt seem to working as it should!

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['adding-attendee'])){

        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

        // Gets current attendee user field and adds the current user to that array
        $current_attendees = get_field('event_attendees', $post_id, false);
        $current_attendees[] = $current_user;

        // Update acf user field
        $attendee_key = "event_attendees";
        update_field( $attendee_key, $current_attendees, $post_id );

        $current_url = "//" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        wp_redirect( $current_url, 301 );
        exit;

        }       

?>
```

Comment: Where & when are you calling this code - e,g, your plugin file, hooking into a particular action or on page load? When you say "not working as it should", can you give specific details please? Its difficult to find a problem when you don't know what it is :)

Comment: Sure, sorry. So this code is just sitting in my form php file, which im calling in the form 'action'. Its loading the form processing file fine as iv already tested that, but doesnt seem to be updated the ACF field.
Iv outputted the $current_attendees field in my template and it just returns a basic array of the user ID's that are attending. 
Then ive also outputted the current users id and thats returning fine. But the updating of the field doesnt seem to be happening

Comment: If you're trying to save the value from the front end, take a look at this help page from ACF website: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/saving-a-dynamic-value-from-a-front-end-text-field/

Comment: Ok i think iv found out the issue. Iv moved the form processing to the top of my template rather than in a separate PHP file and it works fine. Im guessing because it isnt getting the wp_get_current_user when sending it off to the other PHP file to process it?